# laravel 5.3 change SQL query of Authentication

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

i am using laravel5.3 and authentication. i want to change email field as non unique field means same email registered multiple time .Register is successful but on login its take only first credentials true . how i remove first from query in laravel Auth .

Answer (score 0):

Every table in a database should have at least one unique column (**primary key/unique key**). The UNIQUE constraint uniquely identifies each record in a database table. The UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints both provide a guarantee for uniqueness for a column or set of columns. A PRIMARY KEY constraint automatically has a UNIQUE constraint defined on it.

If same email is inserted multiple times then you are making your database inconsistent.

You can assign different ACL roles(**Access Control List**) to a user either(**admin,member or both**).

[image: DB Design]

Comment: sorry my question is different .i use only users table not any other and default authentication provided by laravel